# How to show a dot over the name of an author (for a single letter) of latex bibtex?

Tags: bibtex

[image]I have tried the following by modifying the name of the authors. Everything was fine, except the first name of the second author. I want a dot to be displayed over only I of Ihsan. Any help is appreciated, the MWE based on the bib file is displayed for the reference.

```
@article{18,
title={Developing a fuzzy analytic hierarchy process (AHP) model for behavior-based safety management},
author={Da{\u{g}}deviren, Metin and Y{\"u}ksel, {\.{I}hsan}},
journal={Information Sciences},
volume={178},
number={6},
pages={1717--1733},
year={2008}
}
```

Comment: Did you try `{\.I}`?

Comment: Using the `plain` bibliography style and Computer Modern as the font family, your code produces a dotted `I` glyph. Are you maybe using a nonstandard font setup?

Comment: @Sigur Yes. It throws a error, like "Undefined control sequence. Da{\u{g}}deviren M, Y{\"u}ksel {\I"

Comment: I mean to use it in a Springer Format template

Comment: I think that you have to keep the outer braces: `{{\.I}hsan}`.

Comment: Throws the same error @Sigur. Undefined control sequence. Da{\u{g}}deviren M, Y{\"u}ksel {\I

Comment: @SibaMishra - Sigur didn't ask you to write `{\I}`; he asked you to write `{\.I}`.

Comment: I have tried the suggestion suggested by Sigur. But it also did not work.

Comment: "It did not work" is much too unspecific. *What* doesn't work? Do you get an error message, or a warning message. Be more specific.

Comment: Yes. I can send you the screenshot. Just check at the above.

Comment: Moreover, all the letter behave normal, except that I (check reference number 11, on the above attached screenshot). The screenshot is attached on the top. You can check @Mico

Comment: Judging by the screenshot, I'm guessing you either didn't write `{\.I}` as instructed or you didn't re-run BibTeX and LaTeX twice more after editing the bib file. (Actually, I'm guessing you wrote `\{.I}` before re-running BibTeX.)

Comment: Thank God. It is now fixed. We fixed it by adding a dot manually, in the generated .bbl file. Still your above mentioned solution is not working. The same error is being generated after compilation (as shown in the above screenshot).

Comment: @SibaMishra - The code you posted, which contains `{\.I}`, cannot possibly have generated the screenshot you posted, which shows `{I`. For LaTeX to generate an opening curly brace followed immediately by a capital non-dotted `I`, it *must* have encountered `\{I`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50744/discussion-between-siba-mishra-and-mico).

Comment: @SibaMishra - Sorry, am traveling at the moment. It'll be several hours before I have reliable Internet access once again.